# Problems with an array in a class while using JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a serialisation problem. I wish to save and load a block of simple 3d data. I have a class that contains the dimensions (width, height and length) as well as a 3D array of integers. JSON quite happily converts the class to a string for me to save out but it doesn't play so nicely when converting it back again.

The data class:

```
Public class cClusterData {
public int mWidth;
public int mHeight;
public int mLength;
public int[,,] mCellType;

public cClusterData()
{
    mCellType = new int[32,32,32];
}
}
```

The routine that saves it:

```
    public void SaveCluster()
{
    cClusterData lData = new cClusterData();
    lData.mWidth = mWidth;
    lData.mHeight = mHeight;
    lData.mLength = mLength;
    for (int lX = 0; lX < mWidth; lX++)
    {
        for (int lY = 0; lY < mHeight; lY++)
        {
            for (int lZ = 0; lZ < mLength; lZ++)
            {
                lData.mCellType[lX,lY,lZ] = (int)mCell[lX,lY,lZ].mType;
            }
        }
    }

    string lDataString = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToJson(lData);
    cFileUtils.WriteStringToFile("TestCluster", lDataString);
    Debug.Log("Done saving");
}
```

and the function that loads it back in again:

```
    public void LoadCluster()
{
    string lDataString = cFileUtils.LoadStringFromFile("TestCluster");
    cClusterData lData = new cClusterData();
    lData = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<cClusterData>(lDataString);
    Debug.Log("Loaded header " + lDataString);
    // convert cluster data to actual cluster
    mWidth = lData.mWidth;
    mHeight = lData.mHeight;
    mLength = lData.mLength;

    CreateBlankCluster();
    for (int lX = 0; lX < mWidth; lX++)
    {
        for (int lY = 0; lY < mHeight; lY++)
        {
            for (int lZ = 0; lZ < mLength; lZ++)
            {
                mCell[lX,lY,lZ].SetType((cCell.eCellType)lData.mCellType[lX,lY,lZ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything's fine up until it tries to access lData.mCellType at which point it throws up a NullReferenceException thusly:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
(wrapper managed-to-managed) object:ElementAddr (object,int,int,int)

My guess would involve the way the array is set up in the constructor and I'm just missing a line somewhere. But I can't work it out. Bring it on, internets!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in your code snippet, but did you add `[System.Serializable]` before this class? [This](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/304478/serialization-of-custom-class.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/134168/how-to-serialize-an-array-of-classes.html) both started with the same problem, a custom class, and all the solutions appear to have been found by adding that to the top of the class.